# Invalid DateTime - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to format a datetime string that I receive as a parameter. However, I'm getting an invalid date error.

The parameter `params[:job][:start]` for example has the value of `02/22/2018 5:20 PM`.

I am getting an invalid date error from the code below. I am trying to format the date parameter to this format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:00 +0000`

Please notice that the parameter being sent is in 12 hour time and the format that I am trying to format that parameter to is in 24 hour time.

```
DateTime.strptime(params[:job][:start],"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:00 +0000")
```

Comment: You're parsing it as if it's YYYY/MM/DD format but you clearly state it's in MM/DD/YYYY format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should parse the string into the `DateTime` instance in the first place:

```
DateTime.strptime('02/22/2018 5:20 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p')
```

Then you might spit it out in any format you want.

[More info on formatters](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime).